# I am trying to configure onesignal into my react-native app by following the documentation but it shows and error of @override

Tags: react-native, configuration, onesignal

I am trying to configure my react native app with one signal I am following the OneSignal Documentation followed every step but when I added the code in my MainApplication.java it shows this error ( error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype @Override)

I have been trying different solutions available on the internet but none of them worked.

Error:

```
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug
```

Code to add from the documentation:
(MainApplication.java)

```
import com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage() // You must return the ReactNativeOneSignalPackage here
      );
    }
  };

   @Override
    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    return getPackages();
  }
 }
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.onsignalapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage()
      );
    }
    @Override
      public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return getPackages();
      }

    @Override
      protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
      }
    };

    @Override
      public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    @Override
      public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running react-native upgrade, this will update the mainActivity.java. Maybe that will solve your problem

Comment: It was resolved tried multiple thing at the same time didn’t know which one did just restart my laptop after that and it worked.